# Jinja2 can't extend simple layout

Tags: jinja2, extends

I have a layout html file called layout.html that goes as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>

        {% block head %} 
            <div class = "container-fluid">
                <h1>Books </h1> 
                <h1 class = "text-muted">Rate and discover books</h1>
            </div>

        {% endblock %}


        {% block body %} {% endblock %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

and an index layout called index.html that goes as follows:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block head %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>some text</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

but when I render the index.html into the browser with my flask application, all I see is the following text:

[image: this is what it looks like in browser]

Why??
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel pretty stupid now. I realised that whenever you enter the name of a block in the child template that is also present in the parent template, you are overriding that part of the parent template. So in this case, by entering the block head in the child template and leaving it blank, that's exactly what I did, so the text was overridden by no text basically.

Comment: You can use `{{ super() }}` inside the block in the child template to include the parent template's content if you want to add something. Or add a subblock to your `head` block in your layout and override only the subblock.